# Can this quality be achieved in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, lighting, photorealism

[image]

this is a close-up shot of cardboard sheet,
can i achieve this quality in 3d (blender)?

Comment: Hello, yes of course

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's not opinion based at all. 'Quality' can be interpreted in different ways, but that is not relevant. Whatever possible criteria the example image can be evaluated by (apart from artistic/creative) can be replicated using Blender. Blender has tools to make all elements that are required to create it digitally: modelling, texturing, shading, rendering, post-processing. Imperfections can be modelled, sculpted or displacement, shaders don't require properties not supported by Cycles, glare and depth of field is no problem. If provided image was actually made in Blender it would surprise noone.

Comment: A gigapixel image of a carpet made with iridescent fiber strands casting acurate caustics can not be rendered in 64bit float color depth format and CMYK color system in Blender in terms of quality for example... That would not be opinion based statement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Obviously. Blender is designed for CGI creation and has all the tools needed for modelling, creating shaders, lighting, rendering and post-processing images. Modelling tools available are more than sufficient to model geometries way more complex than what is shown in the image. Cycles and even EEVEE render engines are capable of rendering even more complex light interactions than shown. Shaders needed for an image like that are not that complex and there is even functionality to create procedural textures with Blender's material nodes so even textures for something like that can be created without leaving Blender. Compositor nodes are sufficient for achieving depth of field and various glow effects in post-processing and the technical side of the example is very basic - it's just a 1436x866 pixel, 8 bit per channel image in the most popular image format - JPEG.

So the answer is: Not only most definitely yes, but tools available in Blender are adequate for achieving way more complex and sophisticated images in pretty much all aspects the word "quality" can be used to describe an image, except of course artistic value - that's up to the creator, not the tool, because Blender on it's own does not do much. It's up to the artist to use the tool in creative ways to come up with impressive visuals.